# Why is my site displaying my media query incorrectly?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want the site to have three different formats depending on the width of the browser window. Two of my media queries display correctly. The third one however, does not. For some reason, the images inside the divs increase in height a lot and push all of the text out of the div. The only thing that should change about the images is the width. It's weird because the width and margins of the divs display fine so I know the media query is doing something. It's just that the content inside the divs isn't displaying correctly. This all happens when the browser is above 1000px in width.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<head>
    <title>Resi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <strong><li style="font-size:26">RESI</li></strong>

                <li>Rent</li>
                <li>List Apartment</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Help</li>
                <li>Account</li>
                <div id="logindiv">
                    <li id="signup">Sign In</li>

                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
     <img src="http://www.ojc.edu/futurestudents/housingandfood/images/D13_Wunsch01.jpg" alt="college dorm" width = 960px height=470px>

        <div id="search">
            <h6 style="color:white" id="searchheader">Resi. Your alternative to dorming.</h6>
            <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search For Your School, Neighborhood, or City..."> <input type="button" value="Search">
        </div>



        <div class="reasons_1">
            <img class="pics" src="http://scottsdalefurnishedapartment.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/specialedition.jpg">
            <h3>Get more out of your dorm</h3>
            <p>fdsg zfdga gzszv bzsgfA fdzsbgf zgszza gazff</p>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp"><p class="learn">Learn more &#9654</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="reasons_1">
            <img class="pics" src="https://g.foolcdn.com/editorial/images/130138/college_large.jpg" >
            <h3>Save money</h3>
            <p>szhg sfzv hsgfhazf ghfghx fghx dxhfd fgsz gxsg zsfgsz</p>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp"><p class="learn">Learn more &#9654</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class= "reasons_1">
            <img class="pics" src="http://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2012/7/16/1/CI-Dormify_dorm-room-teens-talking-on-sofa_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.231.174.jpeg">
            <h3>Freedom without the worry</h3>
            <p>szfgzgzdf fg sdfgd gfgfgz g fzsg gfg zgfg zz df hj hj </p>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp"><p class="learn">Learn more &#9654</p></a>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <h2>Terms and conditions</h2>
    </div>

</body>
```

So that's the html and here's the css

```
body {
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
min-width: 636px;
}
div{

margin: 5px auto;
}

h1{
margin: 0px;
line-height: 70px;
}

#nav{
background-color: #00AAA0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 40;
}

li{
float: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 0px 15px;
display: inline;
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
color: white;
}

ul{
margin: 0px;
margin-left: -50px
}

#signup{
float:right;
color: black;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
}

#logindiv,#logindiv:hover{
float:right;
background-color:white;
margin: 5px 15px;
height: 30px;
width: 80px;
cursor: pointer;
}

img{
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 
}

#search{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
bottom: 130px;
margin-bottom: -85px;
}


#search input[type=text]{
border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
background-color:#fcfcfc;
margin-left: 5px;
}

input[type=button], input[type=button]:hover {
position:relative; 
left:-6px;
bottom: 1px;
background-color:#FF7A5A;
color:white;
cursor: pointer;
height: 30px;
border: hidden;
width: 90px;
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.search-bar{
margin: 5px auto;
width: 500px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 16px;
}
#searchheader{
font-size: 30px;

}

h2,h6{
margin: 5px auto;
width:500px;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
}


.reasons_1{
float: left;
background-color:white;
margin: 15px;
width: 31%;
min-width: 286px;
height: 350px;
font-size: 19px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) and (min-width: 1000px) {
.reasons_1 {
float: left;
background-color:white;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 2%;
width: 29%;
min-width: 286px;
height: 350px;
font-size: 19px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
position: relative;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.reasons_1 {
float: left;
background-color:white;
margin-left: 5%;
width: 40%;
min-width: 286px;
height: 350px;
font-size: 19px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
position: relative;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.reasons_1 {
float: left;
background-color:white;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 14%;
margin-right: 14%;
width: 70%;
min-width: 286px;
height: 350px;
font-size: 19px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
position: relative;
}
}

.pics{
height:190px;  
width:100%;
}

h3{
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.2;
}
p{
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-family: Circular, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#footer{
height: 250px;
background-color: #00AAA0;
color: white;
clear: both;
width: 100%
}

.learn{
position: absolute;
left: 165px;
top: 300px;
}

a{
color: #FF7A5A;
}
```

Also, this is my first site so any advice on how to make it look better would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `height` has no value on your `img` css. Also, welcome to SO, generally you want to include a minimal reproducible example for us to help on something like jsfiddle, codepen, or other online editor. You're going to get more help that way saving people the trouble of copy/pasting your stuff somewhere just to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of width you are giving to class reasons_1

Answer (score 0):

Your doctype at the top can't just say doctype
Use

under 
you need to close the html 
Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) for the DOCTYPE and ending HTML code

use these sites [these sites](http://1stwebdesigner.com/website-validation/) to validate you code

edit: I can't post html code. :(